# SQL Update beginning of NText in a column in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table in my database called Customers, which has:

```
+------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------+
|Customer ID | Customer_Name | Customer_Address                          |
| 00001      | JohnD         | @ADDR;Number=21;Road=WalterRoad;@ENDADDR; |
+------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

The datatypes for the attributes `Customer_ID(integer)`, `Customer_Name(nvachar)` and `Customer_Address(ntext)`.

I would like to change the text in the Customer_Address. I want to change  only the Road from Walter Road to Spencers Place and I would like to keep all the other information.

Is there anyway of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `REPLACE`:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cfa8/1/0)**

```
UPDATE Customers 
SET Customer_Address = REPLACE(CAST(Customer_Address AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'Road=WalterRoad','Road=Spencers Place')
WHERE Customer_ID = 1
  -- AND INSTR(Customer_Address, 'Road=WalterRoad') > 0;
  -- AND CHARINDEX(CAST(Customer_Address AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'Road=WalterRoad') > 0; -- I am not sure which RDBMS you use
```

You can add optionally `INSTR` to check if it is something to update.

Comment: I get this error message - Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.. when I run this query.